# Generate a bar chart using chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've the following data which am trying to use to generate a bar chart using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/).

```
const sampleData = {
   "data1":[
      {
         "ng_fy":"2019/20",
         "js":"[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"10\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"7\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"8\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"9\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"11\"}]"
      },
      {
         "ng_fy":"2020/21",
         "js":"[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"5\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"15\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"18\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"7\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"1\"}]"
      },
      {
         "ng_fy":"2021/22",
         "js":"[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"10\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"13\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"11\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"6\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"14\"}]"
      },
      {
         "ng_fy":"2022/23",
         "js":"[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"25\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"19\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"17\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"23\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"16\"}]"
      }
   ]
}
```

```
<canvas id="bar_chart"></canvas>
```

I'm having issues with looping through the data and displaying the chart correctly.

I've created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coderscoven/5ecL1zy9/) . As you can see, the information that's being rendered is not correct and the last two years are not being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing data because you're grouping wrong.

Tried to fix it, but couldn't get it working, so I started over. Let me explain (the working snippet below).

---

You were pushing into `dataset` for each `object` inside your `json`, expect
since you're using grouped chars, you need to group based on the labels of all your datasets, what I call `dataLabel`, so not the x-axis, but in in your case the `Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab` etc

---

Since you're dealing with encoded JSON, lets first decode that:

```js
var json = sampleData.data1;
for (let o in json) {
    json[o].js = JSON.parse(json[o].js).reduce((p, c) => ({ ...p, [c.cat_item]: c.ng_value}), {})
}
```

This loops over each item in the `json` array, then decode (`JSON.parse()`) that, and use `reduce()` to change the arrays of object, into an object that looks like:

```json
{
    "ng_fy": "2019/20",
    "js": {
      "Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab": "10",
      "Semen Bulls Purchased": "7",
      "No. Semen doses Procured": "8",
      "No. of Sexed Embryos Procured": "9",
      "Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured": "11"
    }
  }
```

---

Now we can start creating the dataset ChartJS wants:

```
var dataLabels = Object.keys(json[0].js);
var dataset = dataLabels.map(dl => ({
    label: dl,
    data: json.map(o => o.js[dl])
}));
```

First, get `dataLabels` from the first object we have.
Then loop over those, now we just have to loop (`map()`) over `json` to get the all the `datalabel`'s (from above) to get a structure like:

```json
{
    "label": "Semen Bulls Purchased",
    "data": [
      "7",
      "15",
      "13",
      "19"
    ]
},
...
```

---

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("bar_chart").getContext('2d');
var sampleData = {"data1": [{"ng_fy": "2019/20", "js": "[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"10\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"7\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"8\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"9\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"11\"}]"}, {"ng_fy": "2020/21", "js": "[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"5\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"15\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"18\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"7\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"1\"}]"}, {"ng_fy": "2021/22", "js": "[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"10\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"13\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"11\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"6\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"14\"}]"}, {"ng_fy": "2022/23", "js": "[{\"cat_item\": \"Refurbrish NAGRIC & DB Semen Lab\", \"ng_value\": \"25\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Semen Bulls Purchased\", \"ng_value\": \"19\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. Semen doses Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"17\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"No. of Sexed Embryos Procured\", \"ng_value\": \"23\"}, {\"cat_item\": \"Liquid nitrogen semen storage tanks procured\", \"ng_value\": \"16\"}]"} ] }

var json = sampleData.data1;
for (let o in json) {
    json[o].js = JSON.parse(json[o].js).reduce((p, c) => ({ ...p, [c.cat_item]: c.ng_value}), {})
}

var labels = json.map(j => j.ng_fy);
var dataLabels = Object.keys(json[0].js);
var dataset = dataLabels.map(dl => ({
    label: dl,
    data: json.map(o => o.js[dl])
}));

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
      datasets: dataset
    },
});
```

```css
#bar_chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <canvas id="bar_chart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I never would've figured that out. Much appreciation.